# How to blink a div until it is closed?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a div with close image. It should blink until I'am closing the div. I have done like this,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.3.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
 {
//first slide down and blink the alert box
$("#object").animate({ 
    top: "0px"
  }, 2000       ).fadeOut(slow).fadeIn(slow).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);

 //close the message box when the cross image is clicked 
 $("#close_message").click(function()
 {
    audio.pause();
   $("#object").fadeOut("slow");

});
});
 </script>
```

Now div is blinking few time as written in the code. How can make it till the image is closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a combination of jquery + css animation ([JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j2fc9ktx/2/)):

```
<style>
.glowWorm   {
    -webkit-animation: monofader 1s infinite;
    animation: monofader 1s infinite;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes monofader {
    50% {opacity: 0.4;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes monofader {
    50% {opacity: 0.4;}
}
</style>

<div id="object">Message</div>
<div id="close_message">Closer</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#object").addClass('glowWorm');
        $("#close_message").click(function() {
                audio.pause();
                // Fade entirely
                $("#object").fadeOut("slow");
                // Remove glow
            //  $("#object").removeClass('glowWorm');
            });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **[fadeToggle](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/)** in jquery

```
var isFade = true;

function test() {
    if (!isFade) return false;
    $("#object").fadeToggle("slow", test);
}

$("#close_message").click(function () {
   $("#object").hide();// if you want to hide the images when is fadein
    isFade = false;
});
test();
```

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Bala_chandran/nh23cqbo/29/)**

Answer (score 0):

[You can try this to blink until something stops it:](http://jsfiddle.net/p6kd04de/1/)

```
var toggleFn = function() {
    $("p").fadeToggle(500);
};

var intervalId = setInterval(toggleFn, 500);

var stopFadeFn = function() {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
};

setInterval(stopFadeFn, 5000);
```

In your case, you don't want to use a timer to stop the fade, just use an onclick to run `stopFadeFn`.

Answer (score 0):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5wyx6zzh/2/)

Use setInterval to call function

```
function toggleNow() {
    $("p").fadeToggle(500);
};

setInterval(toggleNow, 500);
```